# Coming forward to dispute an assertion

Tags: word-meaning

> Sony Pictures had suffered an unprecedented hacking attack at the hands of a group calling itself the Guardians of Peace.Last week, the US Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI) said its analysis pointed the finger at North Korea. However, many cybersecurity experts **have come forward to dispute this assertion**

1. What does it mean "they have come forward" ?
2. "To dispute an assertion" is very hard to understand. Is it saying that these experts are for FBI statement or against it? Could you simplify "dispute" & "assertion"  , not the definition but equivalents.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can read *come forward* in this specific sentence as "inform the public about their opinions". What opinions? The phrase *dispute this assertion* clearly suggests "disagreement".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, *dispute* is a verb meaning "question whether (a statement or alleged fact) is true or valid" (definition from NOAD).

Also, an *assertion* is "a statement of fact or belief".

Now imagine a scenario where I state something – in other words, I *make an assertion*:

> *Egg nog is a very healthy drink*.

If you disagree, you might *dispute my assertion*:

> *No, J.R.! Egg nog is **not** a healthy drink! It's high in calories and fat*.

NOAD also gives a meaning for the idiom *come forward*:

> **come forward** volunteer oneself for a task or post or to give evidence about a crime

Back to the news story:

- **The assertion**: *North Korea hacked Sony*
- **Disputing the assertion**: *No, North Korea did not hack Sony* (either someone else did, or maybe Sony wasn't even hacked)
- **Who disputed the assertion?** *Cybersecurity experts who came forward*, that is, experts who volunteered to give evidence about the alleged hack.